# Record only a single thread in JDK Flight Recorder

Tags: java, jfr

I'm looking for a way to record only a single thread in a JDK Flight Recording. I'm using the [jdk.jfr.Recording](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/jdk.jfr/jdk/jfr/Recording.html) API to create a flight recording but do not find a way to limit the events only to a single thread.

I know I can restrict to a single thread afterwards in JMC but I would like to configure this before hand to keep the file size to a minimum and make analysis easier.

The use case I have for this is:

I'm dealing with a multi threaded system where multiple jobs run in parallel. For certain long running jobs I would like to create a flight recording on demand. To make analysis easier and keep the file size to a minimum I would like only one single thread to be recorded.

Comment: `certain long running jobs` Normally this would be a task, not a thread.  Tasks are run by generic threads (as in "any old thread," like from a thread pool), so it shouldn't be bound to a specific thread.  So do you actually need to trigger on a specific task, then record that thread?  I'm not an expert on JFR, but that does strike me as potentially important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to prefilter JDK/JVM events per thread. The best you can do is filter it afterwards, for example:

```
$ jfr scrub --include-threads main recording.jfr
```

That way you can keep down the file size, but it won't reduce the overhead. You can also do it programmatically using the [RecordingFile.write](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/jdk.jfr/jdk/jfr/consumer/RecordingFile.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,java.util.function.Predicate)) method.

Filtering can be done on recordings from JDK 11, or later, even though the API and scrub command only exist in JDK 19+.